# OnItemClickListener override OnItemLongClickListener

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement a contextual action mode for a ListView. I read the android developer documentation and i haven't got any problem with that. The problem happened when i test the app and I realized that, the contextual menu show up, but when i released the mouse click the OnItemClickListener triggered. I don't know what to do for make that onlongclicklistener disable the onclicklister when it's called.
Here's the code for the listener.

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Category item = (Category) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            itemId = item.getId();
            startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
            return false;
        }
    });

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Category category = (Category) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            itemDetailPage(category);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Make `return true;` in `onItemLongClick`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should return true on your LongClickListener:

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Category item = (Category) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            itemId = item.getId();
            startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
            return true;
        }
    });
```